# How does one disable the suggested terms in Magento 1.9.3.3

Tags: search, magento1.9.3, search-terms

I have tried disabling the Magento `suggested terms` for their search function by first turning of `autocomplete` in the backend, but this doesn't seem to work. Now I'm looking for another way to make this happen or to make sure that search terms entered by customers do not get added with `use suggested terms` by default.

Any help not involving editing the core code would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: have you tried clearing cache ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this find the catalog search phtml in

```
<yourmagentodir>/app/design/frontend/package/theme/template/catalogsearch/form.mini.phtml
```

You can **comment** the script which does the trick

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
    var searchForm = new Varien.searchForm('search_mini_form', 'search', '');
    searchForm.initAutocomplete('<?php echo $catalogSearchHelper->getSuggestUrl() ?>', 'search_autocomplete');
//]]>
</script>
```

Comment: This is still a method using the core code to switch it of. In addition to this it leave a very ugly arrow beneath the search bar.